# Click button in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

The Button looks like this in HTML:

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> <strong>Gönder</strong></button>`

And I used this in python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

b = webdriver.Firefox()
b.get("####")
url = b.find_element_by_name("link")
url.send_keys("####")
b.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

There are more buttons with `type="submit"` I need only call the 1 specific button

Does anybody know how I can click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible I would ask the devs to include the ID attribute, so you XPath would be resistant to changes. In other case, you can locate the button by the text:

```
b.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text() = 'Gönder']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `click` with `webdriver wait` for element to be `clickable` so element able to receive `click`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-success")))
element.click()
```